# django rest framework: object field permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, suppose that this is my model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS_NEW = 1
    STATUS_VERIFICATION = 2
    STATUS_ACCEPTED = 3

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_NEW, _('New')),
        (STATUS_VERIFICATION, _('Ready for verification')),
        (STATUS_ACCEPTED, _('Accepted')),
    )

    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('Status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_NEW)
```

What would be the best way to implement field permissions so that user can change Project status from 1(new) to 2(ready for verification), but can't change its status to 3(accepted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [serializer validation docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation). If you implement a `validate_status` method in your serializer you can add the logic there.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any way to check if user is admin while validating the field?

Comment: Try accessing `self.context.request.user` http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#including-extra-context — That whole page is worth a read.